# JavaScript - Dynamically update array of nested objects from another array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm working to add, update or remove a nested object from an array based on the objects from another array. For example, I would like to update the `date -> gte` value based on the `update` array, while keeping `entry -> eq` and adding `date -> lte`.

I have attempted with the following snippet but the outcome produces an inflated result with incorrect keys/values.

```js
const existing = [
  { date: { gte: '2021-01-01' } },
  { entry: { eq: 1 } },
  { keep: { eq: 100 } },
];
const update = [
  { date: { gte: '2021-02-01' } },
  { date: { lte: '2021-12-31' } },
];

const outcome = [];

update.forEach((el) => {
  existing.forEach(elem => {
    Object.entries(elem).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      Object.entries(el).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (k === key && Object.keys(v).sort().toString() === Object.keys(value).sort().toString()) {
          outcome.push(el)
        } else {
          outcome.push(elem)
        }
      });
    });
  })
});

console.log(outcome);

// expected outcome
// [
//   { date: { gte: '2021-02-01' } }, 
//   { entry: { eq: 1 }},
//   { keep: { eq: 100 } },
//   { date: { lte: '2021-12-31' } }
// ]

// current outcome 
// [
//   { date: { gte: '2021-02-01' } },
//   { entry: { eq: 1 } },
//   { keep: { eq: 100 } },
//   { date: { gte: '2021-01-01' } },
//   { entry: { eq: 1 } },
//   { keep: { eq: 100 } }
// ]
```

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably in a working code snippet

Comment: I have added a reproducible example with more information.

Comment: When you use `Object.keys().sort()`, you didn't select a specific index. Are you supposed to? I'd expect that you probably need to before using `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough for your case (updates inplace):

```js
const existing = [
  { date: { gte: '2021-01-01' } },
  { entry: { eq: 1 } },
  { keep: { eq: 100 } },
];
const update = [
  { date: { gte: '2021-02-01' } },
  { date: { lte: '2021-12-31' } },
];

while (update.length) {
  const u = update.shift();
  const [p, o] = Object.entries(u)[0];  
  const [k, v] = Object.entries(o)[0];
  const f = existing.find(e => p in e && k in e[p]);
  f ? f[p][k] = v : existing.push(u);
}

console.log(existing);
```